# Not able to access next element of an array javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JS, I am trying to access the next element of an array using onclick function but no luck.

```js
var i, len;
        
    function quiz() {
    var quiz_questions = [
    "who is the founder of facebook?",
    "who is the founder of google?"
    ];
            
    len = quiz_questions.length;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = quiz_questions[i];
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="quiz();">Click</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

can anyone explain me what I did wrong here.

Comment: what is the problem ? Do you have an error ? BTW In your function you set the innerHTML to the last element of your array. If you need to add all elements of your array, you need to modify your code : document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += quiz_questions[i];

Comment: Your code didn't have any kind of error. The output will be last element of array because it overrides the previous array content.

Comment: @oliv37 No, I am not getting any error. When I hit the button I got the second array element, when I again hit the button still the same second array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you iterate through every question, every time you click. Just remove the for loop and put a i++ after setting the question. Maybe checking, if i is less than the array length before it, wouldnt be a bad idea.

```js
var i, len;
i = 0;
        
    function quiz() {
    var quiz_questions = [
    "who is the founder of facebook?",
    "who is the founder of google?"
    ];
            
    len = quiz_questions.length;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = quiz_questions[i];
    i++;
    if(i>=len){
      i=0;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="quiz();">Click</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

make changes in your javascript like:

```
var quiz_questions = [
"who is the founder of facebook?",
"who is the founder of google?"
];

var counter = 0;

function quiz() 
{
counter++;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = quiz_questions[counter-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This statement will keep overwriting the value of the demo div

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = quiz_questions[i];
```

Instead you will need to append the questions to a variable and then add it to the div. This way both the questions will be added to the div

```
var i, len;

function quiz() {
var quiz_questions = [
"who is the founder of facebook?",
"who is the founder of google?"
];

len = quiz_questions.length;
var htmlContent = "";
for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    htmlContent = htmlContent + quiz_questions[i] + "<br>";
}
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = htmlContent;
}
```